Visual Studio comments have strikethrough in Javascript file
Some comments in JavaScript have a strikethrough text on them making them harder to read and darkened out. Tested different theme and device and all do it, unsure if this such a simple thing I'm missing out but it makes my comment structure harder to read.



Are you using any plugins like TODO Highlight?
Maybe its unknowingly configured to strike-through some comments...

Didn't even think of an extension causing the issue! It was the 'Better Comments' extension causing this issue, removed and reloaded, works fine now. Thank you for the guidance!

@Specthildur: Please add the solution as an answer (you can answer your own questions). So that the question be marked as resolved. It will help the others.

It was the 'Better Comments' extension causing this issue, removed and reloaded, works fine now.
